# Flask-Babel working in development but not translating in production

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-babel

I have got Flask-Babel set up and working correctly on my localhost development app (with two languages: `en_GB` and `en_US`).

However, when I try to switch languages on the production app, it does nothing. The `get_locale()` function is returning the correct language (and I can see it is being called multiple times on a page refresh, suggesting it is being called for each required translation), but no actual translations appear.

As I say, it is working perfectly in the development app and I can't see any reason why the behaviour should be any different in production. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

The translation files (`messages.mo` and `messages.po`) are stored in `translations/en_us/LC_MESSAGES`.

**config.py**

```
LANGUAGES = ['en_GB', 'en_US']
```

**babel.cfg**

```
[jinja2: megaseatingplan/templates/**.html]
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

**__init__.py**

```
# Initialise flask-babel
babel = Babel(app)

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    try:
        print("Language loaded from current_user: "+str(current_user.language))
        return current_user.language
    except:
        print("Language loaded from browser: "+str(request.accept_languages.best_match(app.config['LANGUAGES'])))
        return request.accept_languages.best_match(app.config['LANGUAGES'])
```

**Function for manually choosing language**

```
@app.route('/switch_language/<language>')
@login_required
def switch_language(language):
    current_user.language = language
    db.session.commit()

    track_event("User", "Switch language", label=language, value=0, userid=current_user.userid)

    if language == "en_GB":
        flash("Language switched to English (UK)")
    elif language == "en_US":
        flash("Language switched to English (US)")

    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

**EDIT:**
Some extra info. I have confirmed that the `BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES` is pointing to the correct place and have also use `list_translations()` to confirm that it is finding my `en_US` translation file.

Comment: Can you share more information about your production environment? Are you deploying a container? Is it a different OS than your dev?

Comment: @oz123 Development environment is a venv on Windows, production is on Heroku using gunicorn. Is this the information you need?

Comment: This might help you get an answer ... I'm not familiar with Heroku, but it helps. Are you pushing all the files to heroku?

Comment: @oz123 Yes, I can see all of the files in Github, which Heroku builds from

Comment: As a sanity check, have you tried calling `refresh()` (https://flask-babel.tkte.ch/#flask_babel.refresh) when switching language?

Comment: And you could try running the app locally as if it was in production, using Gunicorn and all the same environment variables, where possible.

Comment: @KarlSutt Thank you - just tried calling ```flask_babel.refresh()``` but no luck, I'm afraid

Comment: @Rob Hmm.. OK. I just checked my notes from a few months ago when I was integrating Flask-Babel and I also had to enable the `jinja2.ext.do` extension in babel.cfg. You could try that, but I'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: @KarlSutt Thanks - just tried that, but it didn't help unfortunately. I've added a couple more details to the question in an edit. My hunch was that the production app wasn't finding the translation files, but that seems not to be the case.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you're missing a `db.session.add(user)` before `db.session.commit()`. If it's not a typo, it means that when the user changes the language the update isn't persisted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230997/discussion-between-karl-sutt-and-rob).

Comment: Can you show how you defined User in your database ? 
(The class definition class User(db.Model): ...)

Comment: (I am asking that to make sure User.language is really stored in database. In development you might store current_user as a "global" variable after calling the function switch_language ; And in production, you might multiples processes which cannot share this)

Comment: BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES is updated to show the correct place on the new server correct?

Comment: @JBLaf Yes, it's definitely being stored in the database, but even if it wasn't, it should be getting the value from the browser. But it is, I can see it in the database and recall is using current_user.language.

Comment: @BrandonKauffman I believe so, yes. Would there be a difference between a relative path in development and the same path in production? Surely they should be the same?

Comment: @Rob it depends. If you used windows to linux it would be different if you descend a director .\ becomes ./

Comment: @BrandonKauffman Thanks. I've got it set up at the moment with ```BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES = app.root_path+'/translations'```, but have also tried ```BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES = './translations'``` and ```BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES = '/translations'```

Comment: Since I don't know your setup @Rob I would recommend using the absolute path, but it does appear that should work. As long as ./translations is where the PID is started from and you know that the root path is what you expect
You could the result of ls -R so we know the structure of directory and all the non-sensitive configs

Comment: @BrandonKauffman I've just verified via Heroku Bash that the file system is identical in development and production. As an added bonus, I've also verified that the ```.mo``` and ```.po``` files are present and correct on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a couple of years, but I have finally figured out my problem.

The path to the translations file was `en_us/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`, whereas the locale on Babel was `en_US`. On my local Windows development server, this was not a problem because Windows paths are case insensitive. However, running on Linux on Heroku, the path could not be found (an error message would've helped resolve this long ago).

After deleting the folder from the remote repository and recreating it as `en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue you describe. For me, the problem was that the directories in `BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES` were upper case ('EN'). Renaming the directory with lower case ('en') solved it for my production environment.

I hope this can help you if you did not already solve you problem

Comment: The solution turned out to be very similar to yours (see my answer).